# GPO: Run batch script as local administrator (NOT system) during system startup

Tags: batch-file, group-policy, privileges

This might have been answered before, but I was unable to find a clear answer to my specific issue.

I'm trying to run a batch-script that will trigger installation of a custom written Windows Service written with Topshelf using .Net Framework.

I can install the service by calling the executable with an `install` startup flag appended to it from a batch file. This will install the service and run it as local system within a Windows Service.

I can run this batch script as administrator directly just fine, but it will not work when I try to use it within the context of a startup script in Group Policy Objects (GPO). This is because the start script runs the batch file within the context of the `SYSTEM` account. And this account enviorement does not see the .Net framework properly, causing the installation to fail due to missing .DLL files.

Here is the batch script i'm running:

```
@echo off

:: Check for previously installed probing agent.
if exist C:\vnc-probe-agent (
    goto EXIT
) else (
    goto INSTALL_AGENT
)

:INSTALL_AGENT
mkdir C:\vnc-probe-agent
xcopy /s /v /y \\SERVER\Apps\vnc-probing-agent C:\vnc-probe-agent

cd C:\vnc-probe-agent

timeout 3

C:\vnc-probe-agent\vnc-probe-agent.exe install
C:\vnc-probe-agent\vnc-probe-agent.exe start

timeout 30
:EXIT
```

**Anyone have any clever tricks to run this script as `BUILTIN\Administrator` instead of `SYSTEM`?**

I have tried to use Task Scheduler as well, but this also did not work. It flat out refused to create the task scheduler entry at all with the required settings.

Comment: Task scheduler is the way to go here, and it should work. So try and troubleshoot the error it gives you when setting it up, optionally using `cmd /c c:\path\batch.cmd`. If you still can't get the Task Scheduler option to work, I would suggest creating a new question specifically about that problem so we can help you in that question. Also, keep in mind that you will have to make a network share mapping and specify credentials in the batch file. Its probably failing with SYSTEM just because \\SERVER is unavailable due to an authentication problem.